# Graphing model results of longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing, longitudinal

I am looking to create a graph of longitudinal data by age and sex, similar to the graph in this image [image: longitudinal graph], from this paper https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanpub/article/PIIS2468-2667(20)30258-9/fulltext.

To graph model results in the past, I have used both ggplot2 and ggpredict. I prefer ggpredict because it graphs the results accounting for covariates, but I am OK with graphing in ggplot2 if it can't be done in ggpredict.

I am providing a minimal reproducible example below, with id, wave (2 waves, separated by 6 years), age, sex, tst (total sleep time), and bmi for a covariate.

```
id<-rep(1:50, 2)
wave<-c(rep(1, 50),rep(2, 50))
tst<-c(sample(7:9,50, replace = T),sample(4:7,50, replace = T))

  
mydf<-data.frame(id,wave,tst)

mydf$age[mydf$wave==1]<-sample(40:90,50, replace = T)
mydf$age[mydf$wave==2]<-mydf$age[mydf$wave==1]+6
mydf$bmi<-sample(20:30,50, replace = T)
mydf$sex<-sample(1:2,50, replace = T)
mydf$age.cat<-cut(mydf$age[mydf$wave==1], breaks = 3,labels = c(1,2,3)) 

##Overall model##
(model <- lmer( tst ~ wave + age + sex + bmi +(1|id), data = mydf))
```

I tried to graph it with ggplot2 using the following syntax, however I'm not sure that the graph is exactly what I'm looking for. I would like to graph change in tst between waves 1 and 2, by age group and sex. TST would be on the y axis, age would be on the x axis, with separate lines for age group and sex, with standard errors. The lines will correspond to within-person change in TST between waves 1 and 2.

[image]

I think that the graph right now is showing the between subjects  effects of age on tst, and not taking into account the fact that the data is nested within-person. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ggplot(mydf,aes(x=age, y=tst, color=as.factor(sex), group=as.factor(age.cat), linetype=as.factor(age.cat)))+
  geom_smooth(data=mydf[mydf$sex==1,], method = lm, formula = y~x)+
    geom_smooth(data=mydf[mydf$sex==2,], method = lm, formula = y~x)+
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: The plot in your example is pretty close to what you are describing. Can you explain a bit more about why it doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: The plot in the image is what I'm trying to get. ggpredict gives me something different. I have now included the plot that my syntax produces. My main issues with this graph are a) it produces separate plots for men and women, b)it produces separate plots for wave 1 and wave 2, c) the estimates for each age group encompass the whole age spectrum on the x axis, I am only looking for them to estimate that specific range for the age group.

Comment: But if you want to include separate lines for men and women, and for wave 1 and wave 2, then there are going to be four lines for each age category, each with their own overlapping standard standard error - and the plot effectively ignores BMI. Such a plot would be a mess visually and near impossible for a viewer to interpret. Surely the facets at least give you a shot of seeing the lines and interpreting the plot?

Comment: It's possible I didn't explain what I am trying to do well enough. I want my graph to look almost identical to the first image in my post. For each age category, there would be two lines (one for males, one for females). The line would correspond to the average within-person change between wave 1 and 2. I want the lines to correspond to the min and max of each of my age categories, so the viewer could see what 6 year change in TST looks like if your first measurement is at 40 years old, compared to if your first measure is at, say 60 years old.

Comment: @AllanCameron I have gotten much closer to what I am looking for, but I am still not convinced that this is graphing within-person data. It seems like I am graphing between person results at each age category. Any advice to get me across the finish line? Thanks for any help!